# Btrfs RAID1: How to replace a disk drive that is physically no more there?

Tags: btrfs, disk, replace, raid1

I have a btrfs RAID1 system with the following state:

```
# btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 975bdbb3-9a9c-4a72-ad67-6cda545fda5e
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 1.65TiB
        devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 1.77TiB path /dev/sde1
        *** Some devices missing
```

The missing device is a disk drive that failed completely and which the OS could not recognize anymore.  I removed the faulty disk and sent it for recycling.

Now I have a new disk installed under /dev/sdd.  Searching the web, I fail to find instructions for such a scenario (bad choice of search terms?).  There are many examples how to save a RAID system when the faulty disk still remain somewhat accessible by the OS.  `btrfs replace` command requires a source disk.

I tried the following:

```
# btrfs replace start 2 /dev/sdd /mnt/brtfs-raid1-b
# btrfs replace status /mnt/brtfs-raid1-b
Never started
```

No error message, but status indicate it never started.  I cannot figure out what the problem with my attempt is.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus, Linux kernel 4.4.0-57-generic.

**Update #1**

Ok, when running the command in "non background mode (-B)", I see an error that did not showed up before:

```
# btrfs replace start -B 2 /dev/sdd /mnt/brtfs-raid1-b                                                                                                                     
ERROR: ioctl(DEV_REPLACE_START) failed on "/mnt/brtfs-raid1-b": Read-only file system
```

`/mnt/brtfs-raid1-b` is mounted RO (Read Only).  I have no choice; Btrfs does not allow me to mount the remaining disk as RW (Read Write).  When I try to mount the disk RW, I get the following error in syslog:

```
BTRFS: missing devices(1) exceeds the limit(0), writeable mount is not allowed
```

When in RO mode, it seams I cannot do anything; cannot replace, nor add, nor delete a disk.  But there is no way for me to mount the disk as RW.  What option is left?

It shouldn't be this complicated when a simple disk fails.  The system should continue running RW and warn me of a failed drive.  I should be able to insert a new disk and have the data recopied over it, while the applications remain unaware of the disk issue.  That is a proper RAID.

Comment: Imho is very very bad to use sd* convention,better is to use disk uuid or label when build array or similar

Comment: Try btrfs device del  /dev/sdd /mnt...&& btrfs device add  /dev/sdd /mnt...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Update:**  According to @mkudlacek, this problem has been fixed.*

*For prosperity, here is my answer to why in 2017, I could not rebuild a RAID with a missing drive.*

Turns out that this is a limitation of btrfs as of beginning of 2017.  To get the filesystem mounted rw again, one needs to patch the kernel.  I have not tried it though.  I am planing to move away from btrfs because of this; one should not have to patch a kernel to be able to replace a faulty disk.

Click on the following links for details:

- [Kernel patch here](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg60979.html)
- [Full email thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=linux-btrfs%40vger.kernel.org&q=subject:%22raid1%5C%3A+cannot+add+disk+to+replace+faulty+because+can+only+mount+fs+as+read%5C-only.%22&o=newest)

**Please leave a comment if you still suffer from this problem as of 2020**.  I believe that people would like to know if this has been fixed or not.

**Update:**  I moved to good old mdadm and lvm and am very happy with my RAID10 4x4 Tb (8 Tb total space), as of 2020-10-20.  It is proven, works well, not resource intensive and I have full trust in it.

Comment: Woah, that's insane. Nobody there knows that RAID exists only to improve availability?

Comment: `-o degraded` is the mount option you're looking for. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496853/143394) for an explanation and important gotcha.

Comment: It is important to understand the difference. `mdadm` has no integrity checking mechanism and can not fix discovered errors by itself (`dm-integrity` beneath may help). Unlike volume-managing file systems like Btrfs or ZFS, that do checksums, can figure out which copy of data is corrupted and replace it without user's attention.

Comment: Hello, your answer is no longer valid. I just force-removed one HDD, booted with the degraded RAID and was able to replace the drive with no issues. Kernel 4.19.0-12-amd64, btrfs-progs 4.20.1-2, Debian Buster.

Comment: The only change on https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Kernel-by-version.html mentioning "degraded" is one change in kernel 4.14. https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.14#File_systems lists the change as "Allow a degraded read-write mount if all the raid profile constraints are met" with links to 2 commits describing how they fix slightly different but still related situations. I also did testing on 6.6.8 with a 1G btrfs partition, wiped one of the partitions, mounted it -orw,degraded, did some changes, unmounted and mounted with rw,degraded again and was able to replace partition just fine.

Answer (score 10):

`replace` needs the filesystem to be mounted `rw` to operate.

In a degraded BTRFS RAID1 filesytem, you have one [**and only one**](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#raid1_volumes_only_mountable_once_RW_if_degraded) chance to mount the filesystem `rw` using [`-o degraded`](https://manned.org/btrfs):

> ```
>    degraded
>        (default: off)
>
>        Allow mounts with less devices than the RAID profile constraints
>        require. A read-write mount (or remount) may fail when there are
>        too many devices missing, for example if a stripe member is
>        completely missing from RAID0.
> ```

After `rw` mount, find the `devid` of the missing device:

```
btrfs filesystem show /mountpoint
```

Replace the missing  with the new device:

```
btrfs replace start -B <devid> /dev/new-disk /mountpoint
```

Check the status:

```
btrfs replace status /mountpoint
```

[`replace` will resume on reboot](https://lwn.net/Articles/524589/).

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer?  The problem was within the code of Btrfs.  Please delete your answer as it is not of any use in the context of the question.

Comment: @HansDeragon I think `-o degraded` has existed for some time...

Comment: read the accepted answer.  The authors of Brtfs admit that the code was missing the feature to replace the drive.  `-o degraded` did not work.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help you, but I do hope it helps others coming via Google.

Comment: Once the replace operation is finished you may need to convert a few DUP and Single chunks, (appeared while replacing the disk?), to RAID1 profile:  

`sudo btrfs balance start -dprofiles=dup\|single,convert=raid1 -mprofiles=dup\|single,convert=raid1 /mountpoint`.

Double-check with the `sudo btrfs fi usage -T /mountpoint` command.

Answer (score 4):

Add the new drive to the filesystem with `btrfs device add /dev/sdd /mountpoint` then remove the missing drive with `btrfs dev del missing /mountpoint` remounting the filesystem may be required before `btrfs dev del missing` will work.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I updated my question to inform you that I can only mount the Brtfs filesystem in RO, which does not allow me to perform any operation on it.

Comment: use the -o degraded option for mount

Comment: Here is the command I used:  `mount -t btrfs -o ro,degraded,recovery,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show /dev/disk/by-uuid/975bdbb3-9a9c-4a72-ad67-6cda545fda5e /mnt/brtfs-raid1-b`

If I remove 'ro' from the option, I cannot get the filesystem mounted.

Comment: Will btrfs rebalance (duplicate from the remaining good drive) the RAID automatically once the new drive is added and the other deleted?

Comment: (I believe the answer is YES if my eyes believe what `brtfs fi usage /mount` is showing me ...)

Answer (score 3):

`btrfs replace` is indeed the thing to try, but there are two gotchas regarding its invocation: it will only show errors when you use `-B` (otherwise it'll exit with status 0, as if everything is fine, but you'll see "never started" when you check the status), and invalid parameters will throw unrelated errors.

For example, I think my disk is fine but the RAID1 got out of sync somehow (probably a power outage during which the host survived, but the disks are not on backup power and might have come online at slightly different times). To check, when I power down disk B (while mounted), I can read data just fine. When I power down disk A instead (disk B is turned on, and the filesystem was already mounted) then I get errors and corrupt data. So clearly disk A is fine and disk B is corrupt. But disk B appears to function, so I want to re-use it and just rebuild. Therefore I want to replace `/dev/diskB` with `/dev/diskB`.

When I used `btrfs replace start -B /dev/diskB /dev/diskB /mnt/btrfs` it showed me `ERROR: ioctl(DEV_REPLACE_START) failed on "/mnt/btrfs": Invalid argument, <illegal result value>`. So there is a problem with the mountpoint it seems, right? Nope, when I changed the first `/dev/diskB` to `/dev/diskA`, it just worked. The mistake was in the devices, not in the mountpoint.

Similarly, I see the first argument (`2`) is kind of weird. Perhaps the error is wrong and it would work with a device in place of the `2`?

`btrfs replace` has two modes of operating: one where you use the broken device as first argument (after `start -B` or whatever), and a mode (if the first option is unavailable) where you use the working device to be copied from. In either case, the second argument is the disk you wish to use to rebuild with.

Whether the filesystem is mounted read-only or read-write, does not seem to matter. That's why I suspect it's rejecting your arguments and giving you a wrong error, rather than the error being correct.