# btrfs raid1: How to check it is function normally?

Tags: btrfs, raid1

I have `RAID1` configured as described [here](http://www.beginninglinux.com/btrfs)

```
$ sudo mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

Then I mount device and write some data:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
echo "some data" > /mnt/123
```

I have next picture:

```
# btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: 01e1a8a1-be78-47d0-8dc2-2e293265b31b
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 896.00KiB
    devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 4.04GiB path /dev/sde
    devid    2 size 3.64TiB used 4.04GiB path /dev/sdb
```

Then I unplug one device and see next:

```
# btrfs fi show
warning, device 2 is missing
warning, device 2 is missing
parent transid verify failed on 22020096 wanted 11 found 8
parent transid verify failed on 22020096 wanted 11 found 8
Ignoring transid failure
Label: none  uuid: 01e1a8a1-be78-47d0-8dc2-2e293265b31b
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 896.00KiB
    devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sde
    *** Some devices missing
```

[When I mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496853/129967) `/dev/sde` device I see no data:

```
# mount -o degraded /dev/sdb /mnt
# cd /mnt
# ls
```

**Thus I am not sure that `btrfs` function normally.**

1. Why I do not see stored data?
2. Why `btrfs fi show` displays different info?
   c/p from posts above:

```
devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 4.04GiB path /dev/sde
VS  (after removing one device)
devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sde
```

As you can see `used` is differ =(

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same filesystem, you formatted /dev/sdc but examined /dev/sde, so which device was renamed?

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: I am sure. The device name was changed when I rescan devices after unplug/plug: `sudo echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan`

Answer (score 0):

thx to `cono`. He help me. I have no RAID yet:

```
# btrfs fi df /mnt
Data, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=768.00KiB
Data, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B
System, RAID1: total=8.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=0.00B
Metadata, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=112.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B
GlobalReserve, single: total=16.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

The command [suggested at article](http://www.beginninglinux.com/btrfs) does not work correctly

So he suggested me make rebalance manually:

```
# btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt
```

Now it works as expected:

```
# btrfs fi df /mnt
Data, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=512.00KiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=112.00KiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=16.00MiB, used=0.00B
```